# Are train times in Google Maps trustable in Tunisia?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tunisia

I'm checking the timetable for intercity trains in Tunisia on https://www.sncft.com.tn/en/search-result/

Comparing them with Google Maps, they look very different. The official website also looks very questionable, given that for (what seem to be) some very important lines, there are no trips after, let's say, 15:00.

So, are intercity train timetables on Google Maps trustable in Tunisia?

Comment: Probably 'no'; they might be outdated. Just today I compared Google maps with the moroccan rail website, and they were badly outdated. There is little reason to assume that Tunisia would be much better than Morocco.

Answer (score 6):

Google will almost always lag behind changes in time tables, especially in countries where the timetables are not updated on websites well before changes.

If in doubt, trust the train company more than any map service, especially a world wide one.

Answer (score 2):

Train times are very unreliable as lags aren't updated even in the station timetable. Advice from a Tunisian person:

Unless you're traveling very late at night, ditch the train and take a shared taxi for intercity or even neighboring country travel.
They run more frequently (as soon as the taxi is full), hold up to 7 passengers, and have a large storage space at the back for luggage.

find the proper depot for your city and the destination you are heading towards and you will be able to board almost immediately.

1 hour of travel usually costs about 7TND, but could be less.